# FFMPEG LIBVMAF segmentation fault

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-quality

I am trying to compare two videos using the libvmaf in ffmpeg 4.0. I have compiled and installed from source VMAF and FFMPEG and FFMPEG has built-in support for `libvmaf`. That's the ffmpeg configuration:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 20160609
configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --toolchain=hardened --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-libass --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libssh --enable-libtwolame --enable-libwavpack --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdrm --enable-frei0r --enable-ladspa --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --disable-ffplay --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libsrt --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libopenh264 --enable-zlib --enable-openssl
libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
```

My VMAF is version:

```
VMAF Development Kit (VDK) Version 1.3.5
VMAF Version 0.6.3
```

When I try to run the VMAF on both files using the following command I get a segmentation fault error and error about unknown format and segmentation fault. The syntax of my command is the following: 

`ffmpeg -i distorted.nut -i reference.nut -lavfi libvmaf -f null -`

The NUT files in this case are both in raw format. I have tried to convert the nut to mp4 using `libx264` but the result was exactly the same. I have uploaded the log file to [wetransfer_link](https://we.tl/gUNY9Adoky) with the debug information.

If I run the VMAF manually from the VMAF install directory I got the results:

```
./run_vmaf yuv420p 1280 720 reference.nut distorted.nut --out-fmt json
```

This is the aggregated VMAF score:

```
"aggregate": {
        "VMAF_feature_adm2_score": 0.989985319391465,
        "VMAF_feature_motion2_score": 12.065062245699426,
        "VMAF_feature_vif_scale0_score": 0.6955497705160056,
        "VMAF_feature_vif_scale1_score": 0.956442334512976,
        "VMAF_feature_vif_scale2_score": 0.9785004960696057,
        "VMAF_feature_vif_scale3_score": 0.9873306412919364,
        "VMAF_score": 99.37877231666236,
        "method": "mean"
    }
```

I have checked and the library header `libvmaf.h` is under `/usr/local/include`, the library `libvmaf.a` under `/user/local/lib` and all the model files under `/usr/local/share`, so everything looks OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMAF have changed their API yet again. Compile against 1.3.4.

Comment: I confirm that ffmpeg 4.0 and even the latest nightly are compatible only with VMAF VDK v. 1.3.4 or lower. I have opened a ticket in the ffmpeg bug tracker and also with VMAF.